# Booking system using query builder and Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am trying to build an app like airbnb using Symfony 4. I have properties that are listed by users and reservations for these properties. The relation between those entities is OneToMany. One property to many reservations. Each reservation has a start_date and an end_date. I want to run a query that returns all properties that are not taken for certain dates selected by users. My query so far is like this:

```
->andWhere('NOT (reservations.startDate BETWEEN :checkInDate AND :checkOutDate) AND ' .
                'NOT (reservations.endDate BETWEEN :checkInDate AND :checkOutDate) AND ' .
                'NOT (reservations.startDate <= :checkInDate AND reservations.endDate >= :checkOutDate)')
                ->setParameter('checkInDate', new \DateTime($checkIn))
                ->setParameter('checkOutDate', new \DateTime($checkOut))
                ->innerJoin('p.reservations', 'reservations');
```

However this seems to check only the first reservation that shows up in the database for each property and ignores the rest. How can I write the code so that the query checks all reservations made for a property not just the first one in the database. Thank you so much

Comment: if you want to get properties, u need to use properties repository and u can use groupby properties

Comment: I am using property repo. How would the code look like? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Did u add ->groupby(‘p’) statement?

Comment: also I think as a login (reservations .end_date > :checkInDate) AND (reservations.start_date < : checkOutDate);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I created another query for reservations that are not overlapping with the dates selected by users and then used notIn in the property query to get all properties which do not have such reservation. Here is the code. This is the query for the reservations:

```
$subQueryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
        $subQuery = $subQueryBuilder
            ->select('prop.id')
            ->from('App:Reservation', 'reservation')
            ->orWhere('reservation.startDate BETWEEN :checkInDate AND :checkOutDate')
            ->orWhere('reservation.endDate BETWEEN :checkInDate AND :checkOutDate')
            ->orWhere('reservation.startDate <= :checkInDate AND reservation.endDate >= :checkOutDate')
            ->andWhere('reservation.confirmedAt IS NOT NULL')
            ->andWhere('reservation.rating IS NULL')
            ->innerJoin('reservation.property', 'prop')
        ;
```

And this is the query for the properties which returns only properties which are not found in the first query. It uses the property id to check that.

```
$properties = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->select('p')
        ->andWhere('p.approved = 1')
        ->andWhere($properties->expr()->notIn('p.id',  $subQuery->getDQL()))
        ->andWhere('reservations.confirmedAt IS NOT NULL')
        ->andWhere('reservations.rating IS NULL')
        ->setParameter('checkInDate', new \DateTime($checkIn))
        ->setParameter('checkOutDate', new \DateTime($checkOut))
        ->innerJoin('p.reservations', 'reservations')
        ->getQuery();
```